# Elasticsearch range query on number in string format

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an `Elasticsearch` index as follows

```
{
  "Price": "50.99"
},
{
  "Price": "30.99"
},
{
  "Price": "40.99"
},
{
  "Price": "10.99"
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the documents based on a range of `price`. I want to return the documents with a price range of `30-100`. But it is not returning any document.

```
 GET index_name/_search
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "range": {"Price": {"gte": 40, "lte": 100}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Since the `Price` is in String format I'm not able to fetch the documents. I don't have previledges to change the `index`. Is there a way to query it without changing the index?

Comment: You need to update the mapping, that is then most efficient solution in the long run

Answer (score 0):

**Best way : Change the field type to float**

But anyway if you want to keep the field type is string you can use painless script to do that. i.e

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "Float.parseFloat(doc['Price.keyword'].value) >= 40 && Float.parseFloat(doc['Price.keyword'].value) <= 100",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```